# rails where condition works in console, but not in web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

I am new in RoR.

The problem is, I created fully functional product categorization with Ancesrty. But now I want to be able to retrieve products that is under these subcategories.

**This is my categories show controller**

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
```

**Here is categories#show view.**

```
 <b>Name of the category:</b>
<%= @category.name %>
<div class="product"
</div>
</p>

<% unless @category.children.empty? %>


       <ul id="sub-menu"> 
        <% @category.children.each do |sub1| %>
           <%= link_to (sub1.name), sub1 %>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

It all works fine. but now I want to add in view categories/show function that shows all products that is under that category.

I added such code. 
In category/show controller

```
@cat_id = @category.id
@product = Product.where("category_id = ?",@cat_id)
```

In the categories show view I added

```
 <td><%= @product.name %></td>
```

Then clicking on some subcategory where should appear few products, there just shows up   *Product*

To check if the code is right I put in the console. There it works fine and retrieve products related to this category.

I dont understand why then code not working in webserver when I launch application ?

Could it be because of some erorr in Associations ?

Thanks !

Comment: Wow , in Categories controller under action show at the end of the line I added .last Then it works and show product related to that category. But that shows just one. After I added .all It shows up error like undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x563d678>

Comment: what could couse this kind off error, because I need all products related to that category. not just one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller, a more readable way is to use the plural form to indicate that you are expecting more than 1 object

```
@products = Product.where("category_id = ?", @cat_id)
```

Then in the view, just loop through these products

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@product = Product.where("category_id = ?",@cat_id)
```

will return an array if there are any products. So you will need to loop through the array.

```
<% @product.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No problem. The arrows to the left of the answer will up vote and there might be a tick under them to accept.

Answer (score 1):

I accept both of the answers, But I want to suggest to use [Active Record Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for this type of problems. This makes your solution easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch only one product, you can use the `find_by_` helper method of the model:

```
@product = Product.find_by_category_id(@cat_id)
```

With this it will fetch the first matching product which has `category_id` equal to `@cat_id`.

If you want to fetch all the products which belong to a category, you need to fetch all the products as others suggested:

```
@products = Product.where(:category_id => @cat_id)
```

And then in the view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>
<% end -%>
```